# I have combine Angular 9 frontend with ASP.NET 4.7 API backend in one solution file but server side sessions how can handle?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I have combine Angular 9 frontend with ASP.NET 4.7 API backend in one solution file but server side sessions how can handle?

HTTPCONTEXT.CURRENT.SESSION

I have combine Angular 9 frontend with ASP.NET 4.7 API backend in one solution file but server side sessions how can handle?
While i have enter user name and password i have generated jwt token using token generator, i am trying to save user id , email in sessions but its shows null.
HTTPCONTEXT.CURRENT.SESSION

Comment: Can you share some code? It is a little hard to answer with the details provided.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding we can not mix both server side and frontend side.
There is one way that if we want to maintain session through backend it should be stored somewhere in db and frontend should call those api to check if session exist otherwise maintain session from frontend if valid account